# Delete N nodes after M nodes of a linked list

Tags: linked-list

I can't figure out why my code is not working. The question is -

> Delete N nodes after M nodes of a linked list
>
> #### Input:
>
> First line of input contains number of testcases T. For each testcase, first line of input contains number of elements in the linked list and next M and N respectively space separated. The last line contains the elements of the linked list.
>
> ### Example:
>
> #### Input:
>
> ```
> 1  
> 8  
> 2 1  
> 9 1 3 5 9 4 10 1
> ```
>
> #### Output:
>
> ```
> 9 1 5 9 10 1
> ```

And my code is -

```
void linkdelete(struct Node  *head, int M, int N)  
{  
if(head==NULL)    
return;  
Node* temp=head;    
while(1)    
{   
int m=M-1;
while(m--)   
{   
temp=temp->next;     
if(temp==NULL)     
exit;    
}   
int n=N;      
Node* t2=temp;   
while(n--)
{     
t2=t2->next;  
if(t2==NULL)   
exit;     
}          
temp->next=t2->next;     
temp=temp->next;      
}
```

On compiling it's giving RUNTIME ERROR.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- Your code has unbalanced braces. I suppose the missing closing brace should be at the end, but since you have not indented your code, there is no way to know
- You should not `exit`. The function should return. In the second loop should not even even exit the function, but just break out of the loop: you still need to change `temp->next`.
- The iteration of the outer loop may end with `temp==NULL`, so when it starts the next iteration, you will have an invalid reference with `temp->next`. Make the condition of the outer loop `temp != NULL`

Here is a corrected version:

```
void linkdelete(struct Node *head, int M, int N) {
    if (head == NULL) return; 
    Node* temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        int m = M - 1;
        while (m--) {   
            temp = temp->next;
            if (temp == NULL) return; // don't exit, but return    
        }
        Node* t2 = temp->next;
        int n = N;
        while (n--) {
            if (t2 == NULL) break; // don't stop yet
            t2 = t2->next;  
        }
        temp->next = t2;
        temp = t2;
    }
}
```